# Xcode bug, or compile error? "Unable to convert data to string around character"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors, xcodebuild

I was assigned to convert a rather large app to Swift 2. It uses various external frameworks and is mostly based around reading and displaying JSON. I got stuck today with a rather cryptic compiler error (using Xcode 7.2):

[image: Error from Xcode - no information whatsoever]

Xctool wasn't too helpful either:

[image: Xctool output - everything passed up to this point]

Then I ran pure Xcodebuild and it shed at least some light, but not that much really:

[image: Xcodebuild output]

Note the Xcodebuild output indicates an error which seems to be related to NSJSONSerialization. Would you rather say this is an issue with the code, or as Xcodebuild output suggests, this may be a bug with Xcode itself? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: Certainly. Cleaned the project, cleaned build folder, deleted DerivedData - nothing helped.

Comment: The message is clear: file a bug. It really helps to copy/paste so we can reasonably read the text. But if it is a bug in your code did it execute until you made a change?

Comment: Thought posting fairly high-quality screenshots would be a better idea... Lesson learned, I guess.  And you're right, the message clearly indicates filing a bug report. Yet the error before that somewhat pinpoints the issue. The app compiled before transitioning to Swift 2, but that was before lots of changes in the code and before the dependencies were updated (and there are about 10 of them).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Used *Build Phases* to narrow problem to a specific source file. The problem resolved when I made sure that the source file was UTF8-encoded.